# RadioButton Settings

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences, radio

У меня вот такой xml.

```
    <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:title="Settings">
            <ListPreference
                    android:title="@string/pref_header_language"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_language"
                    android:key="language"/>
             ...
    </PreferenceScreen>
```

Вот такой Java код

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers);
            setupActionBar();
            final ListPreference langPref = (ListPreference) findPreference("language");
            ...
            setListPreferenceData(langPref,...);
    }
     protected void setListPreferenceData(ListPreference ... item) {
            String MY_SETTINGS = "com.game.education.youona_preferences";
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(MY_SETTINGS, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editSettings = settings.edit();
            CharSequence[] entryValuesLang = {"1" , "2"};
            ...
            postIf = settings.getString("language","").equals("2");
            if(postIf){
                CharSequence[] entriesLang = { "English", "Русский" };
                item[0].setEntries(entriesLang);
                item[0].setEntryValues(entryValuesLang);
                ...
               }
            else {
                CharSequence[] entriesLang = { "English", "Русский" };
                item[0].setEntries(entriesLang);
                item[0].setEntryValues(entryValuesLang);
                ...
                }
     }
```

Когда нажимаю появляется как на изображение и показывает, что выбран English.
Хочу сменить значение на Русский, вот нажимаю и оно сохраняется. Вопрос в том, как словить, это нажатие.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я бы дополнил немного вопрос, потому что не очень понятно что вы хотите сделать, дайте немного деталей потому что вопрос закроют из-за проблем с качеством

Comment: Да ему просто нужно повесить слушатель на кнопку ОК (UTZI), и получить значение из RadioButtonGroup - кто был выбран Здесь достаточно информации что бы ответить на ваш вопрос: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/alertdialog.php. P.S. Человек дело говорит, постарайтесь в следующий раз писать вопрос более развёрнуто, иначе он будет закрыт.

Comment: Не совсем, мне на сам RadioButton надо как-то повесить слушателя.